# converting string characters in 2D list in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I create a 2D list, here is what I tried

```
list = [[] for i in range(2)]
data = 'abcd'

for row in data:
  for col in row:
    list[:0] = data
```

I got

```
['a','b','c','d', 'a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d']
```

But what I want is

```
['a','b']
['c','d']
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to this without iteration:

```
data = 'abcd'
r = [list(data[:2]) , list(data[2:])]

print(r)
#[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```py
LIST_SIZE = 2
lists = [[] for _ in range(LIST_SIZE)]
data = 'abcd'

for i in range(LIST_SIZE):
    for j in range(LIST_SIZE):
        letter = data[LIST_SIZE * i + j]
        lists[i].append(letter)
```